# AssignProcessToJobObject sometimes fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, windows, process

I know there can be several reasons, but I've recently encountered access denied in scenarios that were working fine in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a recent change after which reusing a job object after calling terminate on it will make AssignProcessToJobObject return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Some probable solutions:

- Do not recycle job objects. Create a new object after calling TerminateJobObject on one.
- Use job object completion ports if possible ([example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=4743)).